# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 but php not working

Tags: 16.04, php, do-release-upgrade

I have a cloud (rackspace) based ubuntu server which I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on April 3rd 2017 (So quite a bit after 16.04 was released) (using the usual do-system-upgrade stuff).  The Server is essentially providing an ROR website with nginx and passenger.  MOST of the site now works fine.  However there is a small portion of the site that uses PHP.

Now on 14.04 PHP 5.5.x was working fine.  However currently I can't even get phpinfo() to work.  This suggests that php is not working on the server.

I've tried the following:

```
cd /
php -v

this gives : 

The program 'php' can be found in the following packages:
 * php7.0-cli
 * hhvm
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
-----------------

Ran:
dpkg -l | grep php
ii  php5                                 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21                     all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cgi                             5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21                     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-common                          5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21                     amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
rc  php5-fpm                             5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21                     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-json                            1.3.2-2build1                              amd64        JSON module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                           5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21                     amd64        MySQL module for php5
```

NOTICE the absence of anything to do with PHP7

====
Question:  I need to get PHP7 working on my site.  Would someone tell me where I went wrong and more importantly what I need to get PHP7 working on ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I had earlier upgraded my laptop from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 so I looked there for php7 to be working.  I'm getting the same messages as on the server.  So it's not just a server upgrade issue but also a 'desktop' upgrade issue as well.

Given the prevalence of PHP sites and hopefully quite a few have upgraded to 16.04 I can't find much on the net regarding this problem....hence I'm thinking I've done something wrong here!!

Comment: Have you tried removing old php packages, and installing new ones? You obviously can make something work without having it installed first.

Comment: @mikewhatever yes of course you are right.  But I DID upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 so I was expecting php7 to be there.  Also if you look at the output of what I attempted first it seems to imply that php7.0-cli at least is present.  I am hoping for either some explanation or some clear guidance as I don't want to mess up my installation further if poss.

Comment: `sudo apt install php7.0-cli` Command install the Php

Comment: OK @A Umar Mukhtar.  That got me further.  If I now run php -v I get : php -v
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies .  However after restarting nginx I'm still getting a 404 Not Found error when trying mywebsite/phpinfo.php.  My phpinfo.php is in the directory containing mywebsite/public/

Comment: my nginx.conf file for the php section looks like this:   location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
 }
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html   : Not sure what to replace it with. Thx for all help